# Several columns in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to have 2 or 3 columns of the code in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- right click on tab
- New Vertical/Horizontal Tab Group

[alt text http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/tabgroups.jpg](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/tabgroups.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 columns, per file, I think that is the limit. See here and scroll down to the section "[Viewing the Same File in a Split View](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/post/Visual-Studio-Split-Views.aspx)"

Comment: Ok this was great to have 2 sections but what i really wanted to have was to split the same file and have it appear side by side not over/under even though that was great too.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, but Visual Studio only allows over/under splits of the same file, and only 2 panes at that. Unless we can somehow hack the IDE to open the same file twice... ;)

Comment: No hack needed. It's built in.

Answer (score 0):

When you are editing the file you want to view, go to "Window" menu and select "New Window". You'll now have "myfile.cpp:1" and "myfile.cpp:2". Then move one of them to another tab as if it were another file.